# Pre-header text for mosaico mailings shows twice

Tags: mosaico

When using the Pre-header Text option in a Mosaico mailing like this:

[image: screenshot]

The preheader text shows twice in gmail like this:

[image: gmail screenshot]

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Basically,  from what I can see in the code ( see Mosaico github issue for details here  https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/issues/582 )  preheader is being conditionally shown depending on "Unsubscribe" link behaviour and display logic in template-versafix-1.html have a flow.

One possible workaround is to set Unsubscribe link value to anything but "None" (both "Unsubscribe" and "Profile" would work) and (optionally) delete Unsubscribe link & text from preheader block